# android error for inflating a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

My logcat shows the following error after clicking a button which will lead to a fragment with map being inflated. I have included the error, code and xml for the fragment. Please help.

Here is the error being displayed

```
08-29 23:34:43.716 2180-2180/com.example.brayo.allgps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brayo.allgps, PID: 2180
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brayo.allgps/com.example.brayo.allgps.LocationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
        at com.example.brayo.allgps.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
        at com.example.brayo.allgps.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:48) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:457)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
        at com.example.brayo.allgps.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:48) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    initVal();
}`
```

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.brayo.allgps.LocationActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Share some code and the fragment's xml.

Comment: Probably duplicated tags in *.xml. Check your layout files against it. Check if  you did not included some layouts which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

*Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment*

Its pretty clear from the logs that there is something wrong in line number 13 with the layout .xml file. Whenever you share logs please make sure you share the source files as well thats makes it a tad easier to help us help you.

**EDIT**

Thanks for updating the question. Here is your problem

Add the following to your  in your layout xml file.

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

So it will be like

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Please edit the question and share the source files then i  can help you fix the issue more easily. @brianbmn